# Set margins on print - @media print not working

Tags: javascript, css

When I load my page I set the margin of the container div with Javascript to avoid that the page 'jumps' when the scrollbar shows. Hence, the default value is auto - but the actual value is defined with JS

However, when I then want to print the page, I would like the margins to be set back to auto (or some chosen value)

I have tried with:

```
@media print { .container { margin: 0px; }}
@page { .container { margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; }}
```

And with an independent style sheet for media="print" with:

```
.container { margin: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wish to override the inline style set by JavaScript?

Try this inside of your `media="print"` stylesheet:

```
.container { 
    margin: 0px !important; 
}
```

Inline styles take precedence over stylesheets unless you specify the `!important` rule.

Comment: Interesting :) I just learned something new... Would like to give you credit for it - but need 15 rep and I'm new here...